# how to make double for loops faster in R

Tags: r, recursion

I am trying to do the below calculation using R. my function is recursive and it uses a double for loop to calculate values of "result" matrix. Is there a method to replace the for loops or achieve the if condition faster?

```
x<-rnorm(2400,0, 3)
y<-rnorm(400,0,3)
no_row<-length(x)
no_col<-length(y)
input<-matrix(data=1,nrow = no_row, ncol = no_col)
result<-matrix(nrow = no_row, ncol = no_col)
calculation<-function(x,y)
{  
for(i in 1:no_row)
 {
  for(j in 1:no_col)
  {
    z<-exp(x[i]-y[j])
    result[i,j]<-(z/1+z)
   }
 } 
 new_x<-x-1
 new_y<-y-1
 residual<-input-result    
 sq_sum_residulas<-sum((rowSums(residual, na.rm = T))^2)
 if(sq_sum_residulas>=1){calculation(new_x,new_y)} 
 else(return(residual))
}
output<-calculation(x,y)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar I am trying to code Rasch analysis using R. This section is the main part of the analysis where the residual matrix is calculated. this is an iterative calculation and it stops when squared sum of residuals becomes less than 1.The actual x,y arrays & input matrix have same dimensions but the values are different. my function is so slow that it takes more than an hour to finish the calculation.I am trying to make it faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `outer` function is the tool you are looking for.

Compare these two functions that only generate the `result` matrix

```
x<-rnorm(100,0, 3)
y<-rnorm(100,0,3)

calculation<-function(x,y)
{  
  result <- matrix(nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
  for(i in seq_along(x))
  {
    for(j in seq_along(y))
    {
      z<-exp(x[i]-y[j])
      result[i,j]<-(z/1+z)
    }
  } 
  result
}


calculation2 <- function(x, y){
  result <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) { z <- exp(x - y); z / 1 + z})
  result
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  calculation(x, y),
  calculation2(x, y)
)

Unit: microseconds
               expr     min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
  calculation(x, y) 1862.40 1868.119 1941.5523 1871.490 1876.1825 8375.666   100
 calculation2(x, y)  466.26  469.192  515.3696  471.392  480.9225 4481.371   100
```

That discrepancy in time seems to grow as the length of the vectors increases.

Note, this will solve the speed for your double `for` loop, but there seem to be other issues in your function.  It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do, or why you are calling `calculation` from within itself.  As you have it written, there are no changes to `x` and `y` before it gets to calling itself again, so it would be stuck in a loop forever, if it worked at all (it doesn't on my machine)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have omitted the steps where new_x and new_y are calculated for making the question short,this will prevent the loop from running forever.

Comment: I am trying to code Rasch analysis using R. This section is the main part of the analysis where the residual matrix is calculated. this is an iterative calculation and it stops when squared sum of residuals becomes less than 1.The actual x,y arrays & input matrix have same dimensions but the values are different. my function is so slow that it takes more than an hour to finish the calculation.I am trying to make it faster

Answer (score 1):

To complete Benjamin answer, you shouldn't use a recursion function. You should instead use a while loop with a max_iter parameter.

Reusing Benjamin function:

```
calculation2 <- function(x, y){
  result <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) { z <- exp(x - y); z / 1 + z})
  result
}

calculation <- function(x, y, max_iter = 10){
  input <- matrix(data=1,nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
  sq_sum_residulas <- 1 # Initialize it to enter while loop
  new_x <- x            # Computation x: it will be updated at each loop
  new_y <- y            # Computation y
  n_iter <- 1           # Counter of iteration
  while(sq_sum_residulas >= 1 & n_iter < max_iter){
    result <- calculation2(new_x, new_y)
    new_x <- x - 1
    new_y <- y - 1
    residual <- input - result    
    sq_sum_residulas <- sum((rowSums(residual, na.rm = T))^2)

    n_iter <- n_iter + 1
  }
  if (n_iter == max_iter){
    stop("Didn't converge")
  }
  return(residual)
}
```

If you try to run this code, you will see that it doesn't converge. I geuess there is a mistake in your computation. Especially in `z/1 + z` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Benjamin @Emmanuel-Lin Thanks for the solutions :)  I was able to solve the issue with your inputs. Please find below the sample data set and code. The solution converges when sq_sum_residual becomes less than 0.01. This is more than 12x faster than my code with double for loops.Sorry for the confusion created by the sample data & new_x, new_y calculation provided in the question.

```
Input is a dichotomous 9x10 matrix

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
3  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
4  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
5  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
6  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
7  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
8  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
9  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0



 x<-c( 2.0794415,1.3862944,0.8472979, 0.8472979, 0.8472979,0.4054651,0.0000000, -0.8472979, -1.3862944)
    y<-c(-1.4404130, -1.5739444, -1.5739444, -1.5739444, -0.7472659, -0.1876501, 1.1986443 , 0.7286407,2.5849387,2.5849387 )
    result<-matrix(nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
    calculation<-function(x,y)
    {
      result<-outer(x,y,function(x,y){ z<-exp(x-y);z/(1+z)})
      result[!is.finite(result)]<-NA
      variance_result<-result*(1-result)
      row_var<- (-1)*rowSums(variance_result,na.rm=T)
      col_var<- (-1)*colSums(variance_result,na.rm=T)
      residual<-input-result
      row_residual<-rowSums(residual,na.rm=T)#(not to be multiplied by -1) 
      col_residual<-(-1)*colSums(residual,na.rm=T)
      new_x<-x-(row_residual/row_var)
      new_x[!is.finite(new_x)]<-NA
      new_x<as.array(new_x)
      new_y<-y-(col_residual/col_var)
      new_y[!is.finite(new_y)]<-NA
      avg_new_y<-mean(new_y, na.rm = T)
      new_y<-new_y-avg_new_y
      new_y<-as.array(new_y)
      sq_sum_residual<-round(sum(row_residual^2),5)
      if(sq_sum_residual>=.01)
      {calculation(new_x,new_y)}
      else(return(residual))
    }
    calculation(x,y)
```